# linq to sql - query to find items without children

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

i am trying to write a linq query that doesn't fire a million child queries.

what i want to do is something like this in sql

```
select incoming.id, incoming.message, outgoing.message
from incoming
left join outgoing on incoming.id = outgoing.originalMessageId
where outgoing.message is not null
```

so basically i am doing the left join just do i can find the objects that don't have children.

is there a way to do this, AND return a typed bunch of the "incoming" items...?

sounds simple, and i've tried a few different approaches but i think i'm suffering from lack of sleep so my brain isn't making it happen :(

thanks in advance 
Doug

Comment: I'm confused. Are you sure you got the column names in your SQL correct? I'm thinking it should read    select incoming.id ... not id.incoming

Comment: I hate doing outer joins with the EF!

Comment: yep had my sql wrong - sorry i've fixed it

Comment: I'm also wondering how this is a left join. Due to the null check for a property on the right hand table, there will be no unmatched rows from the left. If my thinking cap is screwed on right, wouldn't this therefore be an inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
Incoming
.Join(
    Outgoing
        .Where(o => o.message != null),
    i => i.id,
    o => o.originalMessageId,
    (i,o) => new {Incoming=i, Outgoing=o}
)
```